# Get data incoming in routes PUT with SILEX

Tags: php, http, routes, put, silex

Get data incoming using `$request->get('bar')` in routes PUT using SILEX

```
$app->put('foo/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) use ($app){
  return var_dump($request->get('bar')); //return null 
});
```

Why return null? How do I access data?

Comment: silly question - are you setting bar in your query? ie. http://localhost/yoursite.php?bar=foo

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because `var_dump` returns null. `var_dump` prints the content of the variable to screen, but does not return it. You may be looking for `var_export`.